# Using variables for events on dynamically generated control

Tags: forms, powershell

I have a function `Add-TextBox`, which creates a `TextBox` control, and assigns a block to it's event handler.

The problem I am facing is that the block is presumably being called with global namespace, and the variables declared inside the `Add-TextBox` function aren't accessible to it. How do I make them accessible?

**Edit**: added full code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function Add-Control() {
    Param (
        [System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form,
        [string]$ControlType,
        [System.Windows.Forms.Control]$AfterControl = $null,
        [int]$Padding = 0
    )

    $control = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.$ControlType

    $control.AutoSize = $true

    $x = 5
    $y = 5

    if ($AfterControl) {
        $y = $AfterControl.Location.Y + $AfterControl.Size.Height + $Padding
    }

    $control.Location = "5,$y"

    $form.Controls.Add($control)

    return $control
}

Function Add-TextBox() {
    Param (
        [System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form,
        [string]$Placeholder = "",
        [System.Windows.Forms.Control]$AfterControl = $null,
        [int]$Padding = 0
    )

    $control = Add-Control -Form $Form -ControlType "TextBox" -AfterControl $AfterControl -Padding $Padding

    $control.Add_GotFocus({
        Write-Host "Placeholder is null: $($Placeholder -eq $null)"
        if ($this.Text -eq $Placeholder) {
            $this.ForeColor = "Black"
            $this.Text = ""
        }
    })

    $control.Add_LostFocus({
        if ($this.Text -eq "") {
            $this.ForeColor = "Darkgray"
            $this.Text = $Placeholder
        }
    })

    return $control
}

$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form

$textbox = Add-TextBox -Form $form -Placeholder "(XXXXXX, npr. 012345)"

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I can use `.GetNewClosure()` on script blocks to capture the local variables and retain them.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function Add-Control() {
    Param (
        [System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form,
        [string]$ControlType,
        [System.Windows.Forms.Control]$AfterControl = $null,
        [int]$Padding = 0
    )

    $control = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.$ControlType

    $control.AutoSize = $true

    $x = 5
    $y = 5

    if ($AfterControl) {
        $y = $AfterControl.Location.Y + $AfterControl.Size.Height + $Padding
    }

    $control.Location = "5,$y"

    $form.Controls.Add($control)

    return $control
}

Function Add-TextBox() {
    Param (
        [System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form,
        [string]$Placeholder = "",
        [System.Windows.Forms.Control]$AfterControl = $null,
        [int]$Padding = 0
    )

    $control = Add-Control -Form $Form -ControlType "TextBox" -AfterControl $AfterControl -Padding $Padding

    $control.Add_GotFocus({
        if ($this.Text -eq $Placeholder) {
            $this.ForeColor = "Black"
            $this.Text = ""
        }
    }.GetNewClosure()) # Here...

    $control.Add_LostFocus({
        if ($this.Text -eq "") {
            $this.ForeColor = "Darkgray"
            $this.Text = $Placeholder
        }
    }.GetNewClosure()) # And here.

    return $control
}


$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form

$textbox = Add-TextBox -Form $form -Placeholder "(XXXXXX, npr. 012345)"

$form.ShowDialog()
```